# Background image makes the text into jpeg artifacts when used with citrix terminal client

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Not sure if it's due to the background image, but i see the text on few stackexchange sites as a low-quality jpeg, when viewed with citrix terminal client. This is likely due to the usage of bachground image under the text.
Please consider using a solid color, if background image is not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a browser that lets you turn off background images in this particular case.